# Array initialization, Java

Tags: java

My assignment is to write a program that declares an array "alpha" of 50 elements of type "double". Initialize the array so that the first 25 elements are equal to the square of the index variable and the last 25 elements are equal to three times the index variable. Output the array so that 10 elements per line are printed.

This is what I have so far, and it is giving me a result of '0.0' so I am clearly doing something wrong. I am brand new to programming and struggling with it a lot. The textbook I have doesn't explain things well (the 'why' behind it all, which I need in order to understand things), and I have searched the internet for help, but I am stumped on this one and could really use some advice on how to get these numbers to print correctly and in the right format as well. I am thinking a modulus might be what I need but they confuse me and I can't even work that out until I get it to print the numbers I need first. Thank you for any advice you can provide. I greatly appreciate it.

```
public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        double[] alpha = new double[50];

        for(i = 0; i < 25; i++);
        {
            alpha[i] = i * i;
        }
        for(i = 0; i >= 25; i++);
        {
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }
        System.out.print(alpha[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` after each `for`. `for(i = 0; i >= 25; i++)` is also wrong, should be `< 25` (or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still in college and I have seen Java a while ago. The college solution should be this:

```
class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] alpha = new double[50];

        for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++)
        {
            // between 0 - 24 (first 25 items)
            if(i <= 24) {
                alpha[i] = i * i;
            // if the first if statement is not correct. Java will go to the next if or else if statement and the first will NOT be executed. If the first i bigger or equal to 25 execute this statement.
            }else if(i >= 25) {
                alpha[i] = 3 * i;
            }
            System.out.print("Index: " + i + " value: " + alpha[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

You can test the code: https://ideone.com/cLm0wy.

What is different about my code and yours?

- After a for loop don't use a semicolon (;). A for and an if use brackets for all the code inside id. The statements in an if and for loop (as well as other loops and so one) need to have a semicolon behind them.
- You defined `i` as a variable. You should not do this, if you start a for loop you initialize the variable you use in the start. A for loop looks like this:

  ```
  for(variable declaration and initialization; condition; operation) {
      // code
  }
  ```
- You can use an if-statement inside a loop, I assume you already learned them as well. I check if `i` is smaller than or is 24 (arrays are zero-indexed, they start from zero) or if `i` is bigger than or is 25 (the rest: 25 to 49).
- You don't need two for loops for this, just an if statement.

I hope this is more clear for you... If not, I am happy to help you further.

One tip I can give you for everything about computer science (programming, networking and so on): Google a lot. Problems are already solved more than 1000 times. This is not an insult, just a tip I give everyone who just started with IT/Computer science.

Good luck!

Comment: `else if(i >= 25)` is not needed, a simple `else` would be fine: `if (i < 25) ... else ...`.

Comment: @pzaenger just to be safe in this exercise and to introduce an `else if`-statement. If he changes the operation to `i--` and let it go backwards or something like that. It could mess up everything. You can never be too safe.

Comment: Thank you for the advice/example! Your explanations were very helpful! I am in an online course and the book is hard for me to understand, but I am finding that having it explained by an actual person makes things much clearer for me. I really appreciate your time and help on this one. I will definitely be able to fix my code now!

Comment: @EmmaBell you're welcome! If you have further questions I would be happy to help your with them. Also be sure to upvote the good answer (arrows on the left) and mark the best answer for you. This for other people who might have the same problem. Enjoy your further course!

Comment: I'm working on fixing my code and it works perfectly now except for the format for the output which needs to be 5 rows of 10 numbers each. I have tried using the do...while loops like @jmodine suggested and (without changing any other part of my code) seemed to get infinite 0.0s. So then I tried the if...else loops and got the same result. This is what I had tried... if(i < 10) { System.out.print(alpha[i] + "\n"); } else if(i >= 10 && i < 20) { System.out.print (alpha[i] + "\n"); } etc. not sure how using this is changing the numbers from 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, etc. to all zeros. any tips?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to figure this part out from another person's post/question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistakes:

1. Semicolon after for statement which means its a null statement and would not execute following statement in a loop. So remove the semicolon as below:

   ```
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   ```
2. You could correct second for loop as:

   ```
   // you could omit i = 25 as the value of i is already 25
   for(i = 25; i < 50; i++)
   ```
3. To print the alpha, you need a loop which would print `alpha` as below:

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       System.out.println(alpha[i]);//println would add new line
    }//if you dont need each number on new line you could use Arrays.toString(alpha)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I hadn't realized I shouldn't be putting a semi-colon after the for statements. I'm sure I learned that last week, but my brain is on overload right now and I'm glad you pointed that out. I also didn't realize I would need a loop for the print function. Again, thank you! This was very helpful to me!

Comment: @EmmaBell Glad it helped. Select the answer by ticking below the vote count if you found it helpful

Answer (score -1):

OK I noticed a few things first your array is declared to have 50 places. Yet you are performing an insert technically infinite times. This happens because you set no end point for you second set of bounds, just i >= 25. Next are you to the phase that while and do while loops are acceptable? Some teachers will not let you use things they have not gone over yet. If so try some thing like this to get your result.

```
public class Arrays
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int i;
  double[] alpha = new double[50];

  // loop for calculating array values
  for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if(i<=24) {
         alpha[i] = i * i;
       }
    if(i>24){
         alpha[i] = 3 * i;
       }
  }

  //loop for printing the array in segments of 10
  for (int j=0;j<50;j++){
   do{
       System.out.print(alpha[j]);
     }while(j<10);
   System.out.print("\n");
  do{
       System.out.print(alpha[j]);
     }while(j>=10&& j<20);
   System.out.print("\n");
   // left the do while loops incomplete so you could get the general idea
  /*do{
       System.out.print(alpha[j]);
     }while(etc......);
   System.out.print("\n");*/
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the down vote with out any explanation. @ Whom ever. Yes there are cleaner ways to do this but not necessarily for a beginner. this is also the only post who answered his whole question including the formatted out put. although thinking about the format you should include either white space or a comma in-between each out put.

Comment: I did the downvote. You answer is just wrong. Did you even try to execute your code? It does not seem so. Or what do you think, when will the first call of `do { alpha[i] = i * i; } while(i<=24);` within the `for`-loop terminate?

Comment: You are correct. I should've tested it first. Its not that the do{} while doesn't execute, i just never gave conditions to exit the first run. So i generated an infinite loop to constantly replace array[0] with 0. Agreed changing the do while to if would fix that problem. I will correct that now for the benefit of others ho may read this post. Forgive me for writing code before my first cup of coffee. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your help! If...else loops are ok, we have covered those. I appreciate your example for showing me a different way. It's always helpful to see how different people approach the same problem. This definitely opened my eyes to another way and will be helpful while I fix my own code. Thank you!!